# why need Subscribe in angular5 when we have two way data binding already?

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular5

I Just started learning angular5, I have experience working with AngularJs. Today learn about Subscribe, Observer and Observerable, I am very confused at these concept.

First thing some into my mind is that angular5 already have two way data binding, if some value change it will change all over the application, right?

Like in AngualarJs, if that's the case why we need these concept in angular5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of the Angular developers now days use reactive forms and also developers moving towards reactive programming. There are so many benefits of observable pattern. You can learn those benefits by googling. I'm going to describe you why observable?
When you fire an event then you are listening by providing a callback function to event as this is very old concept of listening. Observable gives you a better functionality by operators where you can filter results, alter the result according to your choice, can listen by multiple functions (methods), can combine with multiple obervables and so on.

Go ahead and learn reactive programming. It's not limited to Angular. You can use in React and other frameworks too.

Hope it will help

Answer (score 0):

Two way binding as it was in AngularJS had many disadvantages

- Bad performance
- Bigger applications are getting hard to maintain
- many more

You can use ngModel if you need 2-way databinding. There's also a lot of discussion about that on the onternet, so a Google search should get you up to date

Comment: I know disadvantages Two way binding in AngularJS, my question is that. My question is Angular5 also have Two way binding , by using Two way binding we can achieve whats  Subscribe , Observer and Observerable  give.@Bene

Comment: Angular5 use Subscribe , Observer and Observerable because of Bad performance in Two way binding? is that what you want to said @bene